# Limit getEstimates between asymptotes of logistic function (R)

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression

I am using a package in R called nplr, which stands for n-parameter logistic regression, to quantify unknown antigen concentration against a standard curve made with known concentrations. The problem is that when I use getEstimates (which I use to estimate an x value from a known y), it is estimating concentrations (x values) for signal intensities (y values) across the whole range of possible values. This is not good because, as can be seen in the attached picture, at the upper asymptote multiple x values are produced for the same y value. Also, the lower range of the function is not useful because our instrument has a quantitation limit which is slightly above the minimum values plotted.

So, in summary, I need to match x values to known y values only within a specific range of y values.

I think it may be a limitation of the nplr package, because I've read all the documentation on it and the getEstimates doesn't seem to have this ability. A possible solution I am thinking of is to take the parameters of the logistic function output by nplr, then using those values to plot with a more robust package like ggplot2.

Here is the relevant code:

```
h1fit <- nplr(alldata$conc.h1c1, h1stdp, useLog = FALSE, LPweight = 0.25, npars = "all", method = c("res", "sdw", "gw"), silent = FALSE)
h1estimate <- getEstimates(h1fit, alldata$output.h1c1)
```

If I print h1fit, I get the parameters I would need to plot the regression:

```
5-P logistic model
Bottom asymptote: -4.114555 
Top asymptote: 0.9847304 
Inflexion point at (x, y): 0.1105439 0.6000539 
Goodness of fit: 0.9999955 
Standard error: 0.03747073
```

[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP4vN.png)

Any nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you observed is the limitations of 4PL and 5PL curve. The curve can only be used to calculate concentrations between top and bottom asymptotes. My reference is this:
https://www.myassays.com/four-parameter-logistic-regression.html
Hope this is what you are asking for.

BTW, have you tried drc package and compare it to nplr?